# How to make outer div fit child divs?

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

There is two piecharts in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wuKFJ/1). Why the content isn't fit with things that inside of it? What is the reason of overflowing charts out of the content? I want put these charts in to yellow content area. Being a css newbie i don't know that how i can fix it.

```
#content {
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding: 10px 20px 30px 20px;
    background-color:yellow;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

---

```
<div id="content"> 
    This is the content area
    <div id="piechart1" style="position:relative;top:20px;float:left;"></div>
    <div id="piechart2" style="position:relative;float:left;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: add overflow:auto; to content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to clear the floats. I would use `<div style="clear:both;"></div>`
Check updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wuKFJ/4/

Answer (score 3):

It's actually a very simple fix - just make the #content div `overflow:auto` . By default it won't expand to cover the child divs because they are both floated left, which effectively collapses them. Making the parent overflow:auto forces to expand to cover the width and height of the floated divs too.

http://jsfiddle.net/wuKFJ/5/

Answer (score 1):

```
#content {
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding: 10px 20px 30px 20px;
    background-color:yellow;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    overflow: auto.
}
```